# Is there a way in Linux-based operating systems to determine the source of text copied to the X clipboard?

Tags: linux, clipboard

Quick background info: I'm starting to build some software that will run within Gnome- and X-based operating systems to manage clipboard contents. One of the main functions will be to record the source URL of the copied text, if the copied text comes from a browser. I know this is possible on Windows (the [Clipmate](http://www.thornsoft.com/) application does this), but I want to do this within Gnome/X.

I have a sneaking suspicion that this *might* not be possible, because there's no software on Gnu/Linux that comes close to matching the functionality of Clipmate. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated though.

Comment: Klipper seems to have the functionality.

Comment: I've looked into Klipper before (and the similar, but Gnome-based, Glipper). It seems as though they can trigger certain actions based on the text being a URL, but they can't actually _get_ the source URL of the text.

Answer (score 4):

Intercept and decode the [`SetSelectionOwner`](http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-2.html#s-2.1) X message.

Comment: That looks like it will just return Window or NONE when queried. I'm looking for the URL of a page that the user copied text from.